# Where can I find the source code for methods like on_ready and on_message in discord.py?

Tags: python, methods, discord, discord.py

[Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/discord) is the link to the discord.py source code.

I am trying to figure out how methods like on_ready and on_message really work but I can't seem to find the source code of these methods in any of the files. Please provide their source codes or give their links. Thanks!

Comment: These are callbacks and have to be implemented **by you**.

Comment: @KlausD. I think maybe what he's looking for is where it calls these callbacks.

Comment: @KlausD. my program doesn't seem to function when I replace on_message with let's say on_messages... That means that there must be some declaration of the method on_message in the source code and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Do you use `@client.event` or `@bot.event`?

EDIT: So you want to get when is the on_message function called?

Comment: @Gugu72 I use `@client.event`.

Comment: @HSB So what do you want to get exactly? The calls to `on_message`?

Comment: @Gugu72 Yes. Or you could just explain how `on_message` works...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find in the source where does it is called, but I may explain to you how does it work. The function is a callback that can be implemented in the client object.

Example:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client() # Creating a client instance / bot instance

@client.event # Decorator needed
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author)
```

You can use it like that, this example is not useful, it will just print the user name + tag of whoever sends a message in a server the bot is in. But you can use that to make an auto-moderation thing, that check if there is a certain word in the message.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/5e6335750819588062790c6b93d604d3bc7c3862/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L929) is the source code for on_message.